# WCF Contract from XML Soap file

Tags: wcf

I have an inverse task about of WCF service construction.
Have a SOAP Request description XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
<soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <nsp:run xmlns:nsp="http://someurl"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://someurl/NewXMLSchema.xsd ">
   <nsp:routes>
    <nsp:process>number</nsp:process>
   </nsp:routes>
   <nsp:params>
    <nsp:param name="name_1">?</nsp:param>
    <nsp:param name="nam2_2">?</nsp:param>
   </nsp:params>
   <nsp:files>
    <nsp:file name="file_1">b64Binary</nsp:file>
    <nsp:file name="file_2">b64Binary</nsp:file>
   </nsp:files>
  </nsp:run>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

need to design WCF contract which request has a similar description.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

**You can't**, really.

The SOAP XML file is just the data being sent to the service as a request or from the service as a response.

But that doesn't tell you how your **service methods** (your contract) should look like.....

The SOAP messages alone are not enough to define the service. You might be able to define the data structures (the **data contract**) for your WCF service, but not your service contract.

And you won't be able to even define your data contract with this SOAP XML file - since the relevant description of the data types and their structures appears to be hiding in the `http://someurl/NewXMLSchema.xsd` XML schema file .... unless you have that at hand, you're left with the names of the parameters, at best....